# Authenticate user on every request - Spring MVC

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, filter, interceptor

My application receives user creds with each request (header). I need to validate the user creds against database before doing any processing. REST based calls.

What is the best approach / standard practice here?

Plain Servlet Filters?
   Spring Interceptors?
   Or any other alternatives?

Note that I need to connect to the database at each request?

Appreciate your input!

Comment: Don't understand why a downvote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring-security.

You can find an example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/).

Comment: No, but you asked for the "best approach".  I would consider Spring Security the "best approach" as it is highly configurable, annotation and/or config driven, and allows you to fairly easily expand and/or alter your security methods later down the road if you, for instance, decide to do SSO or store users in LDAP instead of a DB.  Plus its a Spring way of handling security, which fits nicely with Spring MVC.